# Elasticsearch sub-aggregation queries that check whether some bucket values meet a condition

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack

Hiii guys!! I am trying to pull out some aggregations that need to perform some specific computation logics per bucket, and it is killing me..

So I have some data tracking who uses what application feature like this:

```
[
    {
        "event_key": "basic_search",
        "user": {
            "tenant_tier": "free"
        },
        "origin": {
            "visitor_id": "xxxxxxx"
        }
    },
    {
        "event_key": "registration",
        "user": {
            "tenant_tier": "basic"
        },
        "origin": {
            "visitor_id": "xxxxxxx"
        }       
    },
    {
        "event_key": "advanced_search",
        "user": {
            "tenant_tier": "basic"
        },
        "origin": {
            "visitor_id": "xxxxxxx"
        }
    }
]
```

The user can opt to trial the app features using `free` tier identity, then register to enjoy other features. The `origin.visitor_id` is calculated from a website user's IP addresses and User-Agent etc.

With this data, I am hoping to answer this question: **"how many people used free trial features BEFORE registering"**.

I came up with a ES query template like below, but couldn't figure out how to write the sub-aggregations that seem to require some more complex scripting against values in the bucket... Any advice is very much appreciated!

```
{
    "aggs": {
        "origin": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "origin.id.keyword",
                "size": 1000
            },
            "aggs": {
                "user_started_out_free": {
                         #    ??????
                         # need to return a boolean telling whether `user.tenant_tier` of the first document in the bucket is `free`
                    }
                },
                "then_registered": {
                         #    ??????
                         # need to return a boolean telling whether any `event_type` in the bucket is `registration`
                },
                "is_trial_user_then_registered": {
                    "bucket_script": {
                        "buckets_path": {
                            "user_started_out_free": "user_started_out_free"
                            "then_registered": "then_registered"
                        },
                        "script": "user_started_out_free && then_registered"
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "num_trial_then_registered": {
            "sum_bucket": {
                "buckets_path": "origin>is_trial_user_then_registered"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [bucket selector aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-pipeline-bucket-selector-aggregation.html) to keep bucket where "trail" and "registration" both exists. Then use [stats aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-pipeline-stats-bucket-aggregation.html) to get bucket count.

**Query**

```
{
  "size": 0, 
  "aggs": {
    "visitors": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "origin.visitor_id.keyword",
        "size": 10
      },
      "aggs": {
        "user_started_out_free": {
          "filter": {
            "term": {
              "event_key.keyword": "basic_search"
            }
          }
        },
        "then_registered": {
          "filter": {
            "term": {
              "event_key.keyword": "registration"
            }
          }
        },
        "user_first_free_then_registerd":{
          "bucket_selector": {
            "buckets_path": {
              "free": "user_started_out_free._count",
              "registered": "then_registered._count"
            },
            "script": "if(params.free>0 && params.registered>0) return true;"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "bucketcount":{
      "stats_bucket":{
        "buckets_path":"visitors._count"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Result**

```
"visitors" : {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
      "buckets" : [
        {
          "key" : "3",
          "doc_count" : 4,
          "then_registered" : {
            "doc_count" : 3
          },
          "user_started_out_free" : {
            "doc_count" : 1
          }
        },
        {
          "key" : "1",
          "doc_count" : 3,
          "then_registered" : {
            "doc_count" : 1
          },
          "user_started_out_free" : {
            "doc_count" : 1
          }
        },
        {
          "key" : "2",
          "doc_count" : 2,
          "then_registered" : {
            "doc_count" : 1
          },
          "user_started_out_free" : {
            "doc_count" : 1
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    "bucketcount" : {
      "count" : 3,
      "min" : 2.0,
      "max" : 4.0,
      "avg" : 3.0,
      "sum" : 9.0
    }
```